# Install torchtext with pytorch 1.13.1 with cuda 11.7

Tags: python, pytorch, torchtext

I currently have PyTorch 1.13.1 with CUDA 11.7 installed and it's working perfectly fine. However, when I try to install TorchText using 'pip install torchtext', it automatically installs PyTorch 2 which causes issues with my existing code that relies on PyTorch 1.13.1 with CUDA 11.7.

When I attempt to install an older version of TorchText, such as 0.14.0, it automatically uninstalls my current version of PyTorch and installs PyTorch 1.13.0 without GPU support.

Is there a way for me to install TorchText without upgrading my PyTorch version and while keeping my CUDA and PyTorch installations intact?

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
pip install torchtext==0.14.0 --no-deps
```

It depends on Pytorch `1.13.0` and you already have `1.13.1` installed so it should work fine.

If it does not work, you will most probably need to downgrade Pytorch

```
pip3 install -U torch==1.13.0+cu117 torchtext==0.14.0 --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117
```